# C# Split String - Split String into Array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I am trying to split a string that the user tiped in. For example:
He types in "Hello". So I want to split this up into an array: ["H","E","L",...]. So how do I use this .split() function?

And how do I save it into an Array?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Try this link it should be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485237/split-string-in-c-sharp-without-delimiter-sort-of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a `string[]` as your desired result `["H","E","L",...` suggests:

```
string input = "Hello";
char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
string[] asStringArray = Array.ConvertAll(chars, char.ToString);
```

`String.ToCharArray` is better than `Enumerable.ToArray` if the string is large because `ToCharArray` knows the size of the string beforehand. So it can initialize the array with the correct size without needing to resize it again and again.

The same applies to `Array.ConvertAll` which knows the size of the array.

Comment: According to [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), `Enumerable.ToArray` fills a `Buffer` that checks if the given sequence implements `ICollection<T>` and if so uses its `Count`, so there wouldn't be much (if any) advantage in using `String.ToCharArray` over `Enumerable.ToArray`. ---- strike that, `string` doesn't implement `ICollection<T>`, so you're absolutely right.

Comment: Good to know since my approach would have been `string[] asStringArray = input.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();`

Answer (score 5):

If you want a `char[]` like `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}` you can simply use `ToCharArray()`:

```
string s = "Hello";
char[] letters = s.ToCharArray();
```

If you want a `string[]` like `{"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"}` you can do it like this:

```
string s = "Hello";
string[] letters = s.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: Could you please add that if `string myString = "hello"` then `char e = myString[1]` is completely valid?

Comment: In the second case, `.ToCharArray()` call is redundant.

Comment: @IvanStoev right, thx. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

```
char[] myArray = myString.ToArray();
```

Comment: Is it possible to just do `myString[0]` in c#? Haven't touched it for long time.

Comment: Yes, myString[0] would return the first char of that string. You could iterate over the string length I guess!

Comment: I wasn't talking about an array. Just random question whether it'd throw an error or not. Tq FYI. :)

Comment: `String.ToCharArray` is better than `Enumerable.ToArray` because it can initialize the array with the correct size beforehand.

Comment: Seems OP asks for a `string[]` and not a `char[]`